# Canonical way to typeset proper descriptions in the style of Principia

Tags: graphics, symbols

I want to typeset "the x such that Phi(x)" thus:

[image: the x such that phi of x]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mthe}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\iota}}
\[ (\mthe x)(\Phi x) \] 
\end{document}
```

This appears to be typographically adequate. However, I believe I read somewhere that using graphics transformations to achieve something like this is not robust. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: This symbol is Unicode 2129, "turned Greek small letter iota".  I don't remember whether this got into the stix font, nor whether (if it did), the orientation is upright or italic.  But that's a place to look.  And if you can provide a published citation, in context, it can be submitted to Unicode for consideration as a math symbol.  Looks to me like a good candidate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Many thanks, barbara. It's in the stix fonts as \turnediota

if you'd like to add an answer, I'll be delighted (and horoured!) to accept it.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I'm always of the opinion that being nice is something truly extraordinary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This symbol is Unicode 2129, in the "letterlike symbols" block.

It's present in the stix fonts, named `\turnediota`.
Only the upright form is provided.